# How to remove link underline in a Button using CSS

Tags: css, button, text-decorations

I am familiar with using `text-decoration: none` in `divs` and `spans`.  However it doesn't seem to work in buttons. I have the following HTML:

```
<a href="upgrade.php">
    <input type="button" class="Buttons" id="Upgrade" value="Upgrade">
</a>
```

and CSS:

```
.Buttons {
    background-color:#D93F87;
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    border-radius:10px;
    font-size:32px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow: -2px 0 #CCC, 0 1px #CCC, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    margin:10px;
}
#Upgrade {
    width:150px;    
}
#Upgrade a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

But I still get an underline. I have tried variations using span but that does not help either. Am I doing something wrong above?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. It is forbidden to put an `<input>` inside a link.  If you want a link to look like a button then use CSS.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?  I'll probably end up using the click event of the button in js since I don't want to change all my buttons (I am sure styling links as buttons will make them look different from the other buttons of that class).

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element — *Content Model: Transparent, but there must be no interactive content or a element descendants.*

Comment: "I am sure styling links as buttons will make them look different from the other buttons of that class" — Not if you do it right.

Comment: To rephrase, _I_ am not capable of styling buttons and links the same. :-)  BTW, as noted in the w3.org link, doesn't **Allowed ARIA role attribute values:
    link (default - do not set), button, checkbox, radio, switch, tab or treeitem** mean that buttons etc. are allowed?

Comment: It means you can set the `aria-role` to `button`, not that you can have a `<button>` as a descendant element.

Comment: Leaving aside the sematics and HTML markup--- the OP is attempting a [**parent selector**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) which does not exist

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't think the question is a duplicate of the one you  referenced.  I am not attempting a parent selector - apparently I have created invalid markup by attempting to put an `<input>` tag inside an `<a>` tag as explained by @Quentin

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
a.mainButton, a.mainButton:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

You can use `.mainButton` or any other class to `a` tag and give it `css`

You have used `#Upgrade` to set `text-decoration` but it will not work as its of `input` ID

You cannot write `css` of parent by targeting child element. you have used `a` tag as the child of `#Upgrade` in your `css` but its the opposite

Comment: I don't want to do this for all a instances, only in specific instances like in buttons...

Comment: see updated answer @Chiwda

Comment: if you dont wabt to do that for all instance, you can use inline style link this `<a href="upgrade.php" style="text-decoration:none"><input type="button" class="Buttons" id="Upgrade" value="Upgrade"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

```
#Upgrade a
```

Means that you select `a` inside `#Upgrade`. In you're case it the opposite, `#Upgarde` is in `a`.

So you can write

```
a #Upgrade {...}
```

Or more simpler

```
#Upgrade {...}
```

Comment: Tried both and they don't work!

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing your anchor target you can try using a class like this

```css
  .Buttons {
    background-color:#D93F87;
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    border-radius:10px;
    font-size:32px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow: -2px 0 #CCC, 0 1px #CCC, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    margin:10px;

   }
   #Upgrade {
        width:150px;
    }
   .test {
      text-decoration: none;

    }
```

```html
<a class="test" href="upgrade.php">
<input type="button" class="Buttons" id="Upgrade" value="Upgrade">
<span>This text is not underline</span>
</a>
```